# Convert To Proper Case Except If It's A TLA In R

Tags: r, regex

I HAVE A SERIES OF CHARACTER VALUES THAT LOOK LIKE THIS.
I Want Them To Look Like This.

I have a set of words however that, when matched exactly, should remain as they are. In this list would be things like ABC.

For the input

SIX SIXTY TEST SUBJECT

with exclusion "SIX"

The desired output would be "SIX Sixty Test Subject".

My current code is this:

```
x <- gsub(paste0("(", paste(exclusions, collapse = "|"), "|\\w)(\\w*)"), "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl = T)
```

Comment: I don't know R but replacing `\b(?!SIX\b)(\w)(\w*)\b` with `\U\1\L\2` should work for the given example. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz3wHj/1). Then, instead of "SIX", you can add the list of excluded words joined by a pipe character. **Edit:** `\b(SIX\b|\w)(\w*)\b` will also work (which seems to be what you were trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```r
x <- "SIX SIXTY TEST SUBJECT"
output <- gsub("(?<=.)\\b(\\S)(\\S*)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "SIX Sixty Test Subject"
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```regex
(?<=.)   assert that some text precedes (ignore the first uppercase word)
\\b     word boundary
(\\S)   match and capture the first character
(\\S*)  match and capture the remaining characters
```

Then we replace with the first captured letter in uppercase followed by the remaining characters in lowercase.  Note that the positive lookahead `(?<=.)` will spare the very first word from the replacement.

**Edit:**

If instead you want to *spare* the literal word `SIX`, then use this version:

```r
x <- "SIX SIXTY TEST SUBJECT"
output <- gsub("\\b(?!SIX\\b)(\\S)(\\S*)\\b", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: _"spare the very first word from the replacement"_ Unless I completely misunderstood the problem, that doesn't seem to be what the OP is after. To quote the OP, _"I have a set of words however that, when matched exactly, should remain as they are"_.

Comment: @41686d6564 Fair enough, I added an answer to cover your intepretation.

Comment: Yeah, it was for a set of exclusions (limited to just SIX for the purpose of illustration) but I can expand that to a list of exclusions easily enough I think

Answer (score 1):

Use the `to_any_case` function from the snakecase package, passing your exclusions to the `abbreviations` argument.

```
library(snakecase)
x <- "SIX SIXTY TEST SUBJECT"
exclusions <- c("SIX")
to_any_case(x, case = "title", abbreviations = exclusions)
#> [1] "SIX Sixty Test Subject"
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to install snakecase package. Error in install.packages : object 'snakecase' not found

Comment: You typed `install.packages(snakecase)` but needed `install.packages("snakecase")`